# Does an Indian passport holder who is a dependant of a British passport holder require a visa to go to Paris, France?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, france, spouses, uk-residents

I have Indian passport with a dependant visa. My husband has recently received a British passport and my baby is British by birth. We are planning to go to Paris.

Do I need a visa and if yes, what is the procedure and what documents do we need to provide?

Comment: Also: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48970/spanish-visa-for-non-eu-spouse-of-a-uk-national

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your status in the UK, [as per the French embassy](http://www.ambafrance-uk.org/Family-members-of-a-Community-National):

> If **you do not** hold a UK resident permit with the mention “Family
> Member of an EEA national” or “permanent residence card”, you must
> hold a Schengen Visa to travel to the Schengen area and evidence that
> you are exercising your right of free movement as the family member of
> an EU National. You must therefore provide with your application form
> the following documents:
>
> - Proof of family link between the visa
>   applicant and the EU / EEA/ or Swiss national: civil document duly
>   legalized/ apostilled by the competent authorities of the issuing
>   country,
> - Proof of nationality of the EU/ EEA/ or Swiss national,
> - Tickets of the EU/ EEA/ or Swiss national
>
> Family members of EU
> Nationals are exempted from the visa processing fees – but not from
> TLS service charge.

Comment: On my visa card it has written PBS DEPENDANT LEAVE TO REMAIN bcoz when i got a visa that time my husband was on ILR bt nw he has got British passport so i m nt sure whether i can apply as a spouse of EU or nt, plus is it compulsory to buy the tickets before visa has been granted? Thanks

Comment: I think you should change your status since your husband is now a UK citizen; I am not sure if staying there with your current status is valid anymore.