# Non-EU spouse of UK citizen Schengen visa requirements

Tags: visas, schengen, eu, spouses

I'm a British citizen and my wife is in the UK on a spouse visa. She holds a BRP card. We're planning to visit Germany and some other Schengen countries, and I've got a question around visa requirements/supporting documents.

I've read in few places (i.e [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/48970/does-a-non-eu-spouse-of-a-uk-national-need-a-visa-to-visit-the-schengen-area)) that the visa requirements are more relaxed if the applicant is a spouse of a UK citizen, and is travelling with the UK citizen.

How relaxed are the requirements? Does my wife need to submit supporting documents for accommodation, finances, flight booking, etc.? Or is it simply submitting the application form alongside the passports and BRP? (i.e standard documentation for Schengen visa application section from [this link](http://www.vfsglobal.com/germany/uk/tourist.html))

Answer (score 4):

> My question is how relaxed are the requirements?

Very.  The visa can be refused only if your wife is a danger to public safety or public health, or her visit would be contrary to public policy.  (Of course, the visa could also be refused if the facts of your application come into doubt, such as that you are traveling together, the validity of your marriage, or your British citizenship, but this answer assumes those facts as given.)

> Does my wife need to submit supporting documents for accommodation, finances, flight booking, etc?

No.

> Or is it simply submitting the application form alongside the passports and BRP? (i.e Standard documentation for schegen visa application section from this link)

It's nearly that simple, but not quite.  She also has to prove that she's related to you, and that you're a British citizen.  For the latter, she should include a copy of your UK passport.  For the former, your marriage certificate would be best.

You'll notice on the Schengen visa application that some questions are marked as not to be answered by applicants who are traveling as family members of EU citizens.  Instead of the tourist link in your question, you should look at the [EU/EEA family member page](http://www.vfsglobal.com/germany/uk/EEA-EU-and-Swiss-national-family-member.html).