# Didn't get France Visa ( Schengen visa) yet but my plane leaves in two days

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, france, schengen-visas, uk-residents

I'm Indian citizen with UK residence permit holder(my husband is British)
we decide to visit France for this summer holidays, so i applied for my France visa as i'm not EU member but i have residence permit so i can applied for France visa over here. we already book hotel and flight tickets as per needed document to submit for France visa(with return ticket). but i didn't get any appointment to the TLScontact centre. (till mid may they don't have dates) they suggest us to do visa through agency. we selected agency and submitted my bio metric and application.(on 26th April early date provided by agency)

I didn't get any confirmation yet about my visa status(still in progress), my travel date is 5th may Sunday.

**can anyone guide me what to do?** i have one day to go (weekend is off)
**Is there any way to get temporary document to enter in France through embassy?**

Comment: When did you apply for the visa?  Did you apply as the family member of an EU citizen?  (Did you pay the visa fee?)

Comment: Related https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/115359/non-eu-spouse-of-uk-citizen-schengen-visa-requirements

Comment: i applied on 13th april then they have to appointment for my bio metrics and  submit my appointment with documents they suggest me go through agency i applied through agency on 15th and submitted document on 17th. as visa centre is full with application they couldn't take early date and  on 26th april i submitted my bio metrics. yes i paid visa fee.

Comment: @RedBaron thank you but not related i already applied for France visa, which i didn't get so i  need help to solve this issue if anybody have any knowledge regarding that.

Answer (score 1):

> yes i paid visa fee

That suggests that you applied as a "normal" applicant rather than as the family member of an EU citizen.

The visa for an EU citizen's family member is free of charge, and it is supposed to be processed quickly.  Two days is probably too little time, however; I suppose it could take as much as a couple of weeks.

You might be able to modify your current application by getting in touch with TLS at the contact information on the French government's page [Applying for a French visa in the United Kingdom](https://uk.ambafrance.org/Applying-for-a-French-visa-in-the-United-Kingdom).  You could also try sending a message via the consulate's [contact page](https://uk.ambafrance.org/Contact-us-21735).  I do not see a telephone number on the site, but a search engine gives +44 20 7073 1200.  I suspect that you won't have much luck getting to talk to the right person, but it is worth a shot.

Another option would be to travel to France by train or boat and apply at the border with proof of your marriage.  We have had a few reports of success this way.  Then you would only lose your plane tickets, not the accommodation.

Comment: are you sure? because you might right but because i'm doing through agency thats why they are charging me money.

Comment: i already tried this consulate's contact page but they just submit my issue and they did nothing for it, it's so stressful.

Comment: @RuchaBhattJoshi There is a separate visa fee (which goes to the consulate) and processing fee (which goes to TLS), though you might pay them together. What was the amount that you paid? Did you submit your marriage certificate? The [handbook (pdf)](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/sites/homeaffairs/files/policies/borders/docs/c_2010_1620_en.pdf) says that you are supposed to be able to submit your application directly to the consulate to avoid the TLS fee. Did they not offer that option? The handbook also says that you should be able to call for an appointment as a regular local phone call.

Comment: @RuchaBhattJoshi also "Processing times for a visa application lodged by a third-country national who is a family member of an EU citizen covered by the Directive going beyond 15 days should be exceptional and duly justified."